# Redirect forum address phpBB3

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I've created a forum using `phpBB3`,
The address I got is :      `http://<FORUM NAME>.com/phpBB3`

I would like to change it to `http://<FORUM NAME>.com` (without the `phpBB3`)

Is it possible to create another forum  addressed to the second URL I mentioned, that uses the same SQL database as the first forum?

Comment: Its a lot of hard work for two boards to share the same database, the most obvious thing that stands out is that avatars and attachments won't work properly because the paths will be different. If you don't need the data to be shared between two boards then you can use the same database, but use different table prefixes. Is it two boards you want or just the URL changing?

Comment: @Eeji, Thanks for reply. I would like to change just the URL, is it problematic to use the same DB or there is another way to change the site address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/phpbb3` part of the URL refers to the directory on the server that your forum is installed in. If you move all of the folders and files out of the phpbb3 directory into your websites root directory (usually either `htdocs` or `public_html`) then the URL will then become `http://<FORUM NAME>.com` This is best done via FTP and not your hosts file manager to help prevent corruption of any files.

Only do this if you don't already have pages at `http://<FORUM_NAME>.com` otherwise you will overwrite anything already there that share any file names.

If you do move everything, once finished log into your phpBB admin control panel and under 'Server configuration -> Server settings' make sure 'Force server URL settings' is set to 'No' and all the internal links on your board will adapt themselves to the new URL.

IMPORTANT! Before you do ANYTHING make sure you download a backup of the files and the database, then if anything goes wrong you can easily put things back again.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please guide me further how to make a backup and reload it in case of accident? Thanks.

Comment: using FTP download everything from your server to your computer, thats the files done. For the database, log into your hosting control panel and go to whatever they provide for maintaining databases (usually phpMyAdmin), select the database you use for the forum and export it (to include structure and data). This will save a copy of the whole db to your computer. If my answer above has helped can you please up vote it and mark it as accepted please :)

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean in 'This is done via PTF and not your host file manager'?

Comment: use an FTP client (FileZilla is a good one) to transfer files as hosts tools have been known to cause problems in the past.